# Qual è il significato di "tovaglia" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Nella vetrina, il manichino di una donna slanciata, sportiva, ostentava un braccio nudo: la sua mano impugnava un attrezzo enigmatico, simile a una racchetta da neve. La donna sorrideva. Era una donna finta, ma tutte le donne qui – anche quelle vere – sembravano finte. Non erano vestite di nero. Non portavano la **tovaglia** in testa. Né il corpetto ricamato né le sottane.

Sapreste spiegarmi cos'era questa "tovaglia" menzionata in questo testo? Le accezioni che ho trovato nei dizionari che ho consultato parlano di pezze di tessuto da mettere sulla tavola o sull'altare, ma non appare niente che si possa portare nella testa di una donna. Si tratta di un fazzoletto?

Comment: Vedo che se ne parla qui: http://mirtonotizieglocali.it/index.php/notizie/715-storia-del-costume-popolare-della-pacchiana-minturnese.html.

Comment: Anche [qui](https://m.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=833204073539076&id=774212416104909) si spiega che la "tovaglia" è "un fazzoletto di mussola da testa orlato da merletti o ricami che una volta inamidato diventa rigido e che fissato con due spilloni copre la testa e scende sulla schiena".

Comment: Se ne parla anche [qui](http://web.tiscali.it/cristoforosparagna/Storia%20di%20Minturno/La%20Pacchiana.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [questo repertorio (inventario) del 1627,](https://books.google.it/books?id=xwS5CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=tovaglia%20testa%20medievale&source=bl&ots=GASSxEk4J6&sig=ACfU3U0MD1LXYESCK6kLeRt6UId4gMZFhA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4yueCgo7gAhWD16QKHQXLC50Q6AEwDHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=tovaglia%20testa%20medievale&f=false) tra le varie cose compare:

> Quattro *tovagliole* da donna da testa e spalle

Indica un grande fazzoletto con cui le donne, fin dal medioevo, si coprivano testa e spalle.

Le tovaglie vengono anche citate in [Dante Alighieri - *Il fiore* - 1283,  CXC](https://it.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Fiore/CXC):

> Sì non dea nessun don, che guari vaglia, 
>   A null’ amante, tanto
>   l’apregiasse: 
>   Doni borsa, guanciale o *tovaglia*,
>
> O cinturetta che poco costasse, 
>   Covricef[f]o o aguglier di bella
>   taglia, 
>   O gumitol di fil, s’egli ’l degnasse

Answer (score 3):

Per aggiungere una precisazione alla risposta di @abarisone, essendo i protagonisti del romanzo originari di Minturno, nel contesto del brano il vocabolo probabilmente si riferisce specificamente alla tovaglia minturnese, che in questa [fonte](https://m.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=833204073539076&id=774212416104909) viene descritta come

> un fazzoletto di mussola da testa orlato da merletti o ricami che una volta inamidato diventa rigido e che fissato con due spilloni copre la testa e scende sulla schiena.

Anche [qui](http://mirtonotizieglocali.it/index.php/notizie/715-storia-del-costume-popolare-della-pacchiana-minturnese.html) si spiega

> A completare tutto è il caratteristico copricapo, la **“tovaglia”**, inamidata che si porta fissata con due spille, su un'acconciatura formata da trecce arrotolate, la tovaglia di mussola e orlata con merletto o con pizzo, e scende rigida dietro la nuca.

Se ne parla anche [qui](http://web.tiscali.it/cristoforosparagna/Storia%20di%20Minturno/La%20Pacchiana.htm), testo in cui si menziona anche il "corpetto ricamato" che appare nel brano citato nella domanda:

> Vivace e antico costume è quello della nostra donna. La *pacchiana* (antico costume tradizionale) indossa un vestito ricco di colori vistosi. La popolana minturnese si copre da capo a piedi, ma il suo costume risponde anche a motivi di bellezza e di gusto, così da renderla molto leggiadra. Di una bellezza fisica tipicamente mediterranea, robusta e fiorente, ma nello stesso tempo dai lineamenti fini, la nostra *pacchiana* impressiona subito per una specie di *tovaglia* inamidata che porta sulla testa, fissata con uno spillo alle attorte trecce del capo, di bianca mussola orlata a merletto o a *pizzo* e ricadente dietro la nuca. In una fiera o in una festa la donna minturnese è facilmente identificabile. Caratteristica è la sua bianca camicia dalle braccia finemente pieghettata e rigonfie sul gomito, da sembrare due ali al vento. Una terza nota peculiare  è data dal *corpetto*, una specie di busto duro, riccamente ricamato in oro, che viene allacciato al petto e ricoperto parzialmente sul davanti da uno scialle (*scòlla*) di tulle o di mussola e di percalle  per i giorni feriali. Le due estremità della *scòlla* vengono fissate dalle *fettucce* dell'elegante grembiule (*zinàle*) a nido d'ape, il quale lega alla vita una lunga gonna (*sànaca*) di lana o di fustagno. Una quarta caratteristica è la lunga pannuccia (*pagnùccia*) rossa, o nero in caso di lutto, che, ripiegata all'insù, avvolge le anche. Distinta è anche la calzatura: scarpa di stoffa con ricamo d'oro. L'effetto che si ha ammirando una donna di Minturno nel tradizionale costume è quanto mai suggestivo, tanto che nel 1934, alle nozze di Umberto I, fu premiato - tra cinquecento vestiti folkloristici - come il più bel costume d'Italia e nel 1981, a Bogotà, in Columbia, fu gratificato dal I° premio mondiale al *Festival Internazionale del Folklore*.

[image]

Immagine tratta da questa [fonte](http://web.tiscali.it/cristoforosparagna/Storia%20di%20Minturno/La%20Pacchiana.htm).